# How to delete a property from an Emberjs Object?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Plain old Javascript object properties can be deleted like so...

```
var foo = {bar: 'baz'};
delete foo.bar
```

How do you delete (not just set to null) a property in an Ember object?

```
var foo = Ember.Object.create({bar: 'baz'});
```

Comment: Have you tried `delete foo.bar` with the Ember Object?

Comment: That works. I love the simple solutions.

Comment: To be honest you are better off setting it to undefined using a setter, if you just do delete it won't notify any observers.

Comment: @Kingpin2k setting it to undefined using setter will not delete it what if it is an object whose reference is stored in some other variable as well?

Comment: delete won't do any different, all it does is remove the property reference from that object.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo.set('bar', undefined)
```

This will delete the attribute and trigger any observer

Answer (score -3):

The same as a normal object:

```
delete foo.bar
```

Comment: This will not correctly trigger observers/computed properties etc.